# Unit testing a spring non - controller method using Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, mockito

**Sample Code**

**Class Which is to be Mocked**

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
@Repository
public class Sample {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Pdt loadpdtType(String planName) 
    {           
       Pdt pdt=new Pdt();

       System.out.println("I am called");
       Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       Query query = session.createQuery("From Dmaster where planName=:planName order by id")
                .setParameter("planName", planName);
       pList = query.list();

       pdt.setSI(pList.get(0).getSI());

       if(planName.equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD")
           pdt.setPDTType("xyz");
       else
           pdt.setPDTType("1234");
       return pdt;
   }

   public Resp getSeq(String Id,String type){
      Resp r=new Resp(Id,type);   
      return r;
   }

}
```

I need to call getpdtType() and getSeq() method from junit. My test Method is as follows

```
class SampleTester {

    @Autowired
    Sample samp;

    Pdt pdt;

    @Test
    public void Testt()     {
        try {
            samp=Mockito.mock(Sample.class);                
            Mockito.when(samp.loadpdtType("sampletext").thenCallRealMethod();
            pdt=samp.loadpdtType("sampletext");         
            Mockito.verify(samp).loadpdtType("sampletext");
            System.out.println("testresult:"+pdt.getPDTType());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And The output is

I am called

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.docs.Sample.loadpdtType(Sample.java:58) [classes/:?]
    at com.docs.Sample$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$f5b2927b.CGLIB$loadpdtType$0() [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at com.docs.Sample.$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$f5b2927b$$FastClassByMockitoWithCGLIB$$15d15c8c.invoke() [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:216) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.invokeSuper(DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.java:19) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.DefaultRealMethod.invoke(DefaultRealMethod.java:21) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.CleanTraceRealMethod.invoke(CleanTraceRealMethod.java:30) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:112) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:34) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:91) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:59) [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at com.docs.Sample$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$f5b2927b.loadpdtType() [mockito-core-1.10.19.jar:?]
    at com.documentation.SampleTester.Testt(SampleTester.java:31) [test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]

Comment: please add the stacktrace and mark the line where the exception occur

Comment: And format your code. The editor has a preview.

Comment: `samp=Mockito.mock(Sample.class);  ` so why would the sessionFactory in samp be non null???

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things here.

1. You don't need the below line:

   > Mockito.when(samp.loadpdtType("sampletext").thenCallRealMethod();

   because you are testing the class `Sample` so it will obviously call the `loadpdtType` method.
2. You need to set the mock for `SessionFactory` in `Sample` class and mock all the method which are being called on `sessionFactory` in `loadpdtType`.

You need something like below:

```
class SampleTester {

@Mock SessionFactory mockSessionFactory;
@Mock Session mockSession;

@InjectMock
Sample samp;

Pdt pdt;

@Test
public void Testt()     {
    try {
        samp=Mockito.mock(Sample.class);                

        pdt=samp.loadpdtType("sampletext");   
        when(mockSessionFactory. getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession); 
// mock other method which are called on Session 

        Mockito.verify(samp).loadpdtType("sampletext");
        System.out.println("testresult:"+pdt.getPDTType());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your session mocking code but it shows **The method getSession() is undefined for the type SessionFactory**

Comment: session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);          
      Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);

Comment: I used above code to mock sessionfactory but still it didnt works

Comment: That was an example to show you abt mocking a method which is called in class under test.  I edited it.

Comment: you need to set that sessionFactory in the `Sample` class. you can do that in setup method. Create a setter in Sample class for sessionFactory and set sessionFactory.

Comment: If I ignore this line 
**Mockito.when(samp.loadpdtType("sampletext").thenCallRealMethod();**
then loadPdtType() method is not invoking.

Comment: SessionFactory is @Autowired and session is already set inside the loadpdtType() method. In which way you are telling to set session in Sample??

Comment: public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        System.out.println("Session factory");
    }

I created this method in Sample.classs and altered SampleTester.java like below

session = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
sessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);          
Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);     
samp.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

Still it didn't works

Answer (score 0):

Hurrah !! Thanks Everyone I got solution to my own question. I was making it more difficult and hard. Configured sessionfactory bean and embeddedWebApplicationContext in MyApp.class and it worked...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApp.class)

@WebAppConfiguration

@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")

public class SampleTester

{
    @Autowired

```
Sample samp;

@Test
public void Testt()     
{           
    Pdt pdt=samp.loadpdtType("sampletext"); 
    Resp r=samp.getSeq("ABC","XYZ"); 
// All assertions for Pdt, Resp follows

}
```

}